# sklearn - How to generate proper labels with multiple values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

In my course, we have to implement a working traffic light recognition algorithm using python with the common modules (numpy, sklearn, etc.)

In my simple_train dataset, there are 209 pictures where each of those pictures has  no, one or multiple traffic lights on it. For simplification, I modified my loading algorithm to just return a single traffic light (if there is one or more).

My independet dataset (picture arrays) has a shape of (209, 720, 1280, 3) and I noticed that I have to reshape it into an 2d array - so my feature set array has a shape of (209, 2764800).

Now there's the tricky part I'm stuck at. Each traffic light consists of four coordinates (x_min, x_max, y_min and y_max). This means for the first three pictures, my label would look like this:

```
array([None, None, (610, 351, 615, 358), ... ])
```

On the first two pictures, there are no traffic lights but on the third one, there's a traffic light with the given boundaries.

Calling the .fit function of the MLPClassifier I get the following error message:

> ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([None, None, (610, 351, 615, 358), ...])

How do I have to modify my label to get this to work?

Comment: You could add `(0,0,0,0)` label, for the `no traffic light`, and attempt. During prediction `(0,0,0,0)` should be defined to be no traffic light. However that is kinda brute forcing. Not sure of the scope of your model, but there are many recognition models out there you can research on.

Comment: No, the task you described is object-detection and will be too complex for scikit-learn models. You can start by only predicting if any traffic light is present in the given picture or not. This can be done by changing the labels to `[False, False, True]` or `[0, 0, 1]` for your given examples.